# Grails Spring Security Last Request URL when AJAX

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm recently facing the problem with last request url after login. Normally, everything works properly. But if I proceed following procedure I have troubles:

1. Open an App in one tab and log in
2. In this tab I go somewhere where AJAX request to the server are proceeded regularly
3. Open a new tab with the app (I'm still logged-in)
4. In this tab I log out
5. In the mean time the AJAX request from the 1st tab is proceeded automatically
   with HTTP 401 (cause I've logged-out)
6. When I try to log in again in the 2nd tab than I receive the JSON of the AJAX request from the 1st tab because it was the last request.

I would suspect that Spring Security would neglect AJAX request for "last request url". Is it possible to set this somewhere? Or is there any good workaround to this?

Thanks,
Mateo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a general way to distinguish ajax requests from "regular" requests initiated by the user navigating a browser. If you can distinguish them in your application (e.g. by mapping ajax requests to specific urls that can be matched against some patterns), you could easily implement what you are looking for. (**EDIT**: An easier way to identify ajax requests is suggested by Sérgio in his below comment.)

The component that is responsible to perform redirection after a successful login is `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, therefore one possibile way to customize the framework's default behavior is to provide your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, and inject it into the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. It should be possible to autowire the `RequestCache` in your class, and decide if you want to replay the last cached request or just ignore it in case it's known to be an ajax request.

Comment: "I don't think there is a general way to distinguish ajax requests from 'regular' requests initiated by the user navigating a browser" - check `request.xhr` [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html)

Comment: @SérgioMichels: That just checks if the `X-Requested-With` header is `XMLHttpRequest` (see [source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-servlets/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ServletRequestApi.groovy#L54)). I have absolutely no idea how reliable this is, but might be an easy solution.

Comment: Thanks for the great input. It helped me a lot, however still fighting with it. I've extended AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and I can access requestCache in determineTargetUrl(). The problem is that this method is called just when normal login, not when the login procedure described above. Is there any other handler for this? Or what I'm missing?

Comment: `determineTargetUrl()` will only ever be called if there is no saved request in the `RequestCache`, which means that changing its behavior is useless for implementing your requirements. You'll have to override `onAuthenticationSuccess()` instead, and implement your logic there: check for a saved request in the cache, if there is nothing, delegate to the super class, otherwise verify if the saved request is an ajax request before redirecting to it.